# How to install valid server certificates in Android Studio, (Not expired ones)

Tags: android-studio

I am currently using the following version of Android Studio

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 10
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.9762515, built on March 17, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b653.34-9746777 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
```

whenever I build any android project and view the download page i see the following table

[image]

[image]

and when i view the server certificates section in preferences i see most of the certificates are expired

[image]

are these related?

do i need to be concerned about this?

how do i fix the failures?

Comment: You have to add the certificate to the Android Studio keystore.

Comment: @PabloValdes where do I source the certificates from

Comment: If you are using zScaler you can check this page: https://help.zscaler.com/zia/adding-custom-certificate-application-specific-trust-store
Back to your question, the certificate has to be provided to you by your organization. Ask who is in charge of managing the zscaler certificate.